# Como gerar uma li apartir desse JSON

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo uma requisicao para obter [esse JSON](https://client-demo-accounts-2.bootstrap.fyre.co/bs3/v3.1/client-demo-accounts-2.fyre.co/379221/MjAxNjAxMjcxMjQyOmRlc2lnbmVyLWFwcC0xNDUzODQwMjgxODk0/init), e gostaria de saber como montar uma li usando essa requisição

```
var url = "data.json";

        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.open("GET", url);
        httpRequest.responseType = "json";
        httpRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
          if (httpRequest.readyState == 4){
            if (httpRequest.status == 200){
              console.log(httpRequest.response);
              console.log(httpRequest.response.headDocument);
              console.log(httpRequest.response.headDocument.authors);
              console.log(httpRequest.response.headDocument.content);
            } else {
                console.log("fiz algo errado xD")
            }
          }
        });

        httpRequest.send();
```

Comment: Você pode usar o [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) para montar um template, então combine o template ao json

Comment: poderia me dar um exemplo usando meu codigo acima?

Comment: Bruno, verifique a formatação e o conteúdo da sua pergunta. Está difícil entender o que você quis dizer.

Comment: Melhorou um pouco, Bruno, mas ainda falta dar um exemplo de entrada e saída. Mostre como é esse seu JSON e como quer que fique o li correspondente a esse JSON.

Comment: @Pablo, ele mencionou a fonte do JSON em outra pergunta... segue o exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/TobyMosque/xtk52m1o/

Comment: @TobyMosque Blz, mas ainda falta explicar como ele quer esse li

Comment: Qual parte do json será usada para montar a lista? Ele é enorme! O headDocument.content ?

Comment: @FelipeMoraes, por isto estamos pedindo um template do que será gerado.

Comment: Isso `httpRequest.open("GET", url);` não deveria ser isto `httpRequest.open("GET", url, true);` pra poder usar o `readystatechange`?

Comment: Amigo eu votaria de cara para fechar a pergunta uma fez que ela continua obscura após 2 dias, não esta clara o suficiente onde é o problema, como acabei de voltar de uma penalidade por votar rápido demais vou votar em deixar aberta até que você reformule a pergunta ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer um foreach para obter os dados:

```
//...
if (httpRequest.status == 200){
    httpRequest.response.headDocument.content.forEach(function(o){
        console.log("source: " + o.source);
        console.log("collectionId: " + o.collectionId);
        console.log("generator ID: " + o.content.generator.id);
        console.log("parent ID: " + o.content.parentId);
        //...
    });
}
//...
```

O seu problema é entender como navegar dentro de um objecto json. Ao entender isso, você irá conseguir construir a sua lista.

Veja o json que foi utilizado na pergunta, existe uma coleção de objectos json dentro do seu array json `httpRequest.response.headDocument.content`.

Os arrays JSON são delimitados por colchetes [ ], com seus elementos separados entre vírgula:

```
{
    headDocument: { //objecto json
        content: [ //array json com uma coleção de objectos json
            { source: 1,collectionId: "155985417", //... }, //objecto json
            { source: 2,collectionId: "556454847", //... }, //objecto json
            //...
        ]
    }
 }
```

Sendo assim utilizamos `forEach` para ter acesso a todos os elementos do array `content`. Cada elemento desse array é um objecto `json` que é passado  como parâmetro para a função callback:

```
httpRequest.response.headDocument.content.forEach(function(o){
    //O parâmetro "o" é um objecto json
}
```

Como o parâmetro "o" é um objecto `json`, podemos navegar por suas propriedades:

```
o.source //source é uma propriedade do objecto "o"
o.collectionId //collectionId é uma propriedade do objecto "o"
//...
```